# Silex JSON style Responses

Tags: php, json, silex

I'm in the process of switching from the RESTler API framework to Silex. Part of the challenge is making sure the responses from our API does not change since we have apps in production that depend on it. Currently the out-of-the-box Silex 2.0 is intercepting our JSON error handler and replacing it with this:

[image: Whoops Message]

What I need as a response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "This API key is not authorized to complete the operation"
  }
}
```

I've found snippets of solutions but they are mostly out of date or I could not get them to work with Silex 2.0.

I could easily do

```
if (!$controllerResponseData) {
    $error = array('message' => 'This API key is not authorized to complete the operation');
    return $app->json($error, 400);
}
```

However this would have to be done at the routes level, forcing me to rewrite all of my controllers. They don't manage errors, those are handled much deeper at the business logic and model layers.

Is their anyway to override the default error handling in Silex? Also, what would be most ideal is having the error handling as it is for debugging but easily switch to JSON error responses in production or for local testing.

Comment: Did you try to look at [Errorhandlers](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html#error-handlers) ?

Comment: @Samundra Yes, this is part of the problem actually. I would need to pass $app throughout the entire application in order to get it down to some of the business logic, validators, and models layers. I just need to intercept the exception from being captured by what I believe to be a symphony. No mater where I do `throw new RestException(400, 'some message')` it get's intercepted and I get the Whoops error.

Answer (score 0):

Use construction try catch. For example:

```
try{
   // your code 
} catch(\Namespace\RestException $e) {
  $error = array('message' => 'This API key is not authorized to complete the operation');
  return $app->json($error, 400);
}
```